# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(NewFlavorPageModule)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I got this error when I go to this page using routerLink

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(NewFlavorPageModule)[[object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object]]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!
> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(NewFlavorPageModule)[[object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object]]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!
> at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:6344:27)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6771:33)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6771:33)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6771:33)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6771:33)
> at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:13756:36)
> at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3286:39)
> at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3331:12)
> at ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10858:12)
> at NodeInjectorFactory.NewFlavorPage_Factory [as factory] (ɵfac.js? [sm]:1:1)
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:1262:35)
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:1216:21)
> at zone.js:1329:21
> at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:443:35)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26194:33)
> at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:442:64)
> at Zone.runTask (zone.js:214:51)
> at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:632:39)
> at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:529:25)
> at invokeTask (zone.js:1727:22)

Here is my code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-flavor',
  templateUrl: './new-flavor.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-flavor.page.scss'],
})
export class NewFlavorPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public fileChooser: FileChooser, public file: File, ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  chooseFile() {
    this.fileChooser.open().then((uri) => {
      alert(uri);

      this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(uri).then(newUrl => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(newUrl))

        let dirPath = newUrl.nativeURL
        let dirPathSegments = dirPath.split('/')
        dirPathSegments.pop()
        dirPath = dirPathSegments.join('/')

        this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(dirPath, newUrl.name).then((buffer) => {
          this.upload(buffer, newUrl.name);
        })
      })
    
    })
  }

  upload(buffer, name) {
    let blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: "image/jpeg" });
    let storage = firebase.storage();

    storage.ref('wing flavors/' + name).put(blob).then(d => {
      alert("Done")
      console.log(d)
    }).catch((error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)))
  }
}
```